# Zig-Zag traversal of list

Tags: algorithms

Suppose that each node of the list has the following structs:

- string
- num
- next

It is given a string $w$. Suppose that $w$ is in the list at a node $p$, of which the struct num has the value n.
We are looking for the value of the struct string of the node that precedes $p$ for $n$ positions in the list.

[image]

So, do we have to traverse the whole list, till we find a node with struct num equal to $n$ and then with a while loop find the desired value or is there also a better way?

**EDIT**:That's what I have tried:

```
Algorithm(pointer L, string w){
    pointer R=L;
    int times=0;
    if (R==NULL) return;
    while (R!=NULL and R->string!=w){
          times++;
          R=R->next;
    }
    n=R->num;
    if (times>n){
        int i=0;
        p=L;
        while (i<times-n){
               p=p->next;
               i++;
        }
        return p->string;
    }
    }
```

Is it right or have I done something wrong?

Comment: To make sure that I understand: if $w=\text{corn}$, then $n=4$, and we want $\text{cat}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, it is like that..

Answer (score 1):

You have a pointer $L$ to the beginning of the list. First, create a new pointer $R$ that also points to the beginning of the list. Now, traverse the list with $R$, looking for the struct with string $w$. While $R$ is traversing the list, you should also keep a count $p$ equal to how many elements $R$ has iterated over. When you find your the struct with string $w$, simply compute $p-n$ and iterate this many times from $L$ to find what you're looking for.

In C++, the algorithm may look something this:

```
int spaces_to_move(LL* R, std::string word_to_find)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(R->w != word_to_find){
        R = R->next;
        i++;

        if(!R){
            std::cout << "Word not found\n";
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return i-R->n;
}
```

Comment: Zeno I edited my post and added an algorithm I tried.. Could you tell me if it is right and if there is a better algorithm? :/

Comment: @evinda I have included a C++ snippet of the algorithm. If you find this answer satisfactory, please accept it.

Comment: I edited my post and added an algorithm.. Could you tell me if it is right?